# Can forces in N be thought of as a length?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

A solid uniform 45.0 kg ball of diameter 32.0 cm is supported against a vertical friction-less wall using a thin 30 cm wire of negligible mass.

(a)make a free body diagram for the ball and use it to find the tension in the wire and (b) how hard does the ball push against the wall?

[image: 1]

I am just wondering if you can think of forces as length? Calculate them just like a length, like any length, M, Cm and so on.

I managed to the exercise by doing exactly this.

MG on ball = 441 newton which means the Y-component of T (String is equal to 441N as well).

I then used this component and the length to find the tension in the String, just like finding the length of the sida a triangle.

441N/Cos(20 degrees) = 470N in the string. And then I did exactly the same for the other part of the string which was equal to 160N.

The string pushes upwards with a force of 470N and the ball pushes to the right with a force of 160N.

I see that other people have found the solution by substituting and stuff like that.

Comment: Not like lengths, but like vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact you have been treating forces just like space vectors, meaning 'things' having a length, a direction and an orientation and that can be added and subtracted using the parallelogram rule. The fact that forces can be treated as vectors is a well-known property of forces.